# How to filter out elements in RDD using list of exclusions (similar to isin)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to filter the arraybuffer using elements in a list similar to `isin` in Dataframe.

```
val booksDF: DataFrame = ...
val Books_Category = List("A","B","C")
val action_books = booksDF.filter($"bk_category_cd" isin (Books_Category: _*))
```

How do I apply same filter using collection on an RDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RDD you can use `contains` method for the list to `filter` out.

supposing you have `dataframe` like

```
+-----+
|books|
+-----+
|A    |
|D    |
|B    |
+-----+
```

and list as

```
val Books_Category = List("A","B","C")
```

You can use `contains` in `rdd` as

```
val filteredRDD = df.rdd.filter(x=>Books_Category.contains(x(0)))
filteredRDD.foreach(println)
```

This should result

```
[A]
[B]
```

**Doing the same in `RDD` itself is also the same**

suppose we have `RDD` and `list` to `filter` as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("A", "D", "B", "E", "F"))
val list = List("A","B","C")
```

Then doing like we did above

```
val filteredRDD = rdd.filter(x => list.contains(x))
filteredRDD.foreach(println)
```

would result

```
A
B
```